# It's possible to put Google Map's Javascripts in the Asset pipeline (Rails)?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, asset-pipeline

I added the javascript needed to load the google maps into my page:

```
<% content_for :head do %>

<script type="text/javascript"
src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=API_KEY&sensor=false">
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
function initialize() {
    var mapOptions = {
        center: new google.maps.LatLng(<%=@lat%>, <%=@lon%>),
        zoom: 5,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    };
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"),
        mapOptions);
}
</script>

<% end %>
```

as you can see i need to pass the parameters latitude and longitude when i load the map.
As i said in the title i want to put these javascripts into the asset pipeline, is it possible if yes how ? thanks

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You should not include the Google Maps API in your asset-pipeline-generated `application.js` file. Instead it should be included as a separate `<script>` tag **before** your `application.js`'s `<script>` tag.

You can then add your `initialize()` method into any file included in your asset pipeline, including `application.js` itself.

You'll probably want to make `@lat` and `@lon` arguments of your `initialize` method though so they can be defined within your pages `<head>`. For example, you might have

```
<head>
  <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=API_KEY&sensor=false"></script>
  <%= javascript_include_tag "application" %>

  <script>
    var latitude  = <%= @lat %>;
    var longitude = <%= @lon %>;
  </script>
</head>
```

and in your `application.js` file you might have

```
function initialize(latitude, longitude) {
  var mapOptions = {
      center: new google.maps.LatLng(latitude, longitude),
      zoom: 5,
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
  };
  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"),
      mapOptions);
}

$(function() {
  initialize(latitude, longitude);
});
```

Comment: Thanks, and i will say that this implementation allowed me to use google maps with turbolinks :)

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't answer your question, but there is a google maps gem that has worked really nicely for me: https://github.com/apneadiving/Google-Maps-for-Rails

Comment: This should be posted as a comment to the Question - as you said yourself, this isn't an answer.